# PHP - select value by key (date), then return values sum

Tags: php, arrays

I may have stupid question but I do not know how to solve my problem.

**What I want to achieve.**

I need to divide the field by date (key) (specifically, I'm interested in the year) and figure out the total amount (value) for each year.

my array:

```
Array
(
    [2017-04-20 15:26:08] => 0.00
    [2016-10-11 13:52:05] => 0.00
    [2016-05-26 13:04:14] => 200000.00
    [2016-05-24 14:32:34] => 0.00
    [2016-05-24 11:32:17] => 0.00
    [2016-03-29 19:02:24] => 79800.00
    [2016-02-16 07:54:38] => 0.00
    [2015-12-16 19:01:55] => 149900.00
    [2015-01-30 15:07:38] => 402103.00
    [2014-11-03 15:13:29] => 0.00
    [2014-10-15 15:58:44] => 129000.00
    [2014-10-06 12:44:52] => 0.00
    [2014-07-28 10:47:45] => 0.00
    [2014-07-23 15:50:24] => 133333.33
    [2014-05-16 12:39:25] => 0.00
    [2014-04-29 13:21:01] => 5045524.00
    [2014-03-04 15:28:03] => 0.00
    [2014-01-13 09:41:47] => 0.00
    [2013-11-26 08:40:20] => 70000.00
    [2013-07-22 12:17:24] => 0.00
    [2012-10-05 13:51:06] => 0.00
    [2012-03-08 15:45:44] => 149880.00
    [2012-03-02 13:11:19] => 0.00
    [2012-02-14 09:26:43] => 0.00
    [2011-12-05 10:44:23] => 0.00
    [2011-12-05 10:33:53] => 1500000.00
    [2011-07-01 14:40:22] => 0.00
    [2011-05-30 09:54:22] => 1680000.00
    [2011-01-13 08:59:14] => 72000.00
)
```

my code:

```
$min_year = date('Y',strtotime(min(array_column($MY_ARRAY,'published_at'))));
$max_year = date('Y',strtotime(max(array_column($MY_ARRAY,'published_at'))));

for($year = $max_year; $year >= $min_year; $year--){
$amount_array = array_column($MY_ARRAY,'contract_amount','published_at');

echo 'Year: ' .$year . ', Total amount for this year: ' . ???? . ' €';

}
```

how should I do it?

edit// part of original array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2898917
            [contract_identifier] => 155/AD00/2017
            [contracting_authority_name] => some company
            [contracting_authority_formatted_address] => address
            [contracting_authority_cin] => 123456789
            [supplier_name] => another company
            [supplier_formatted_address] => 
            [supplier_cin] => n123456789mber
            [subject] => contract title
            [subject_description] => 
            [signed_on] => 2017-04-19
            [effective_note] => 
            [contract_price_amount] => 0.00
            [contract_price_total_amount] => 0.00
            [note] => 
            [published_at] => 2017-04-20 15:26:08
            [changed_at] => 2017-04-20 15:10:09
            [change_note] => 
            [internal_id] => 155
            [internal_note] => 
            [confirmation_file_name] => 
            [confirmed_on] => 
            [source_id] => 2
            [description] => 
            [reference] => 
            [effective_from] => 2017-04-21
            [effective_to] => 
            [crz_department_name] => department
            [crz_status_name] => 1
            [crz_type_name] => 1
            [crz_kind_name] => 2
            [crz_confirmation_status_name] => 5
            [crz_attachments_title] => 11111
            [crz_attachments_file_name] => 
            [crz_attachments_file_size] => 
            [crz_attachments_scan_file_name] => 2898918_dokument.pdf
            [crz_attachments_scan_file_size] => 373463
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2635819
            [contract_identifier] => 241
            [contracting_authority_name] => ...
```

...
...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Loop through the whole stuff.
2. Create another array.
3. Get the date part and parse the year.
4. Cumulatively add the years as the key and value as the sum.
5. Display.

Code:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        "2017-04-20 15:26:08" => 0.00,
        "2016-10-11 13:52:05" => 0.00,
        "2016-05-26 13:04:14" => 200000.00,
        "2016-05-24 14:32:34" => 0.00,
        "2016-05-24 11:32:17" => 0.00,
        "2016-03-29 19:02:24" => 79800.00,
        "2016-02-16 07:54:38" => 0.00,
        "2015-12-16 19:01:55" => 149900.00,
        "2015-01-30 15:07:38" => 402103.00,
        "2014-11-03 15:13:29" => 0.00,
        "2014-10-15 15:58:44" => 129000.00,
        "2014-10-06 12:44:52" => 0.00,
        "2014-07-28 10:47:45" => 0.00,
        "2014-07-23 15:50:24" => 133333.33,
        "2014-05-16 12:39:25" => 0.00,
        "2014-04-29 13:21:01" => 5045524.00,
        "2014-03-04 15:28:03" => 0.00,
        "2014-01-13 09:41:47" => 0.00,
        "2013-11-26 08:40:20" => 70000.00,
        "2013-07-22 12:17:24" => 0.00,
        "2012-10-05 13:51:06" => 0.00,
        "2012-03-08 15:45:44" => 149880.00,
        "2012-03-02 13:11:19" => 0.00,
        "2012-02-14 09:26:43" => 0.00,
        "2011-12-05 10:44:23" => 0.00,
        "2011-12-05 10:33:53" => 1500000.00,
        "2011-07-01 14:40:22" => 0.00,
        "2011-05-30 09:54:22" => 1680000.00,
        "2011-01-13 08:59:14" => 72000.00
    );
    $sum = array();
    foreach ($arr as $year => $value) {
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($year));
        if (!isset($sum[$year]))
            $sum[$year] = 0.0;
        $sum[$year] += $value;
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
array(7) {
  [2017]=>
  float(0)
  [2016]=>
  float(279800)
  [2015]=>
  float(552003)
  [2014]=>
  float(5307857.33)
  [2013]=>
  float(70000)
  [2012]=>
  float(149880)
  [2011]=>
  float(3252000)
}
```

Comment: @LubosBelan Good that it works. But: 1. You should parse date using `date()` and `strtotime()` method. 2. In lower PHP versions, without initliasing the values, if you try to increment, it might throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Would be way more easier to do something like:

```
$sum = array();
foreach ($MY_ARRAY as $date => $value) {
    $year = substr($date, 0, 4);
    $sum[$year] = (isset($sum[$year]) ? $sum[$year] : 0) + $value;
}
print_r($sum);
```

Comment: _Notice: Undefined offset: 2017_